# working on SAS without SASpy and with jaydebeapi

Tags: python, sas, jaydebeapi, saspy

Well i cant use SASpy since its corporate.
so i am trying python with jaydebeapi

code is simple

```
import jaydebeapi
conn=jaydebeapi.connect('''com.sas.rio.MVADriver ''' , 'jdbc:jkfbsdkfk//fdsf',jars='sas jars')
```

getting following error 
jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.sas.rio.MVADriver not found

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What does 'its corporate' mean? Why can't you use it?

Comment: saspy is an open source package

Comment: sure but on some systems you are not allowed to install your own python packages or packages that would be needed by them

Comment: Since it's corporate I would say the issue is a ticket to the SAS Admin or IT team.  As they don't let you install packages they probably don't let you install jdbc drivers.  If you know the driver is available I would say the execution session environment space does not have the appropriate paths specified.

Comment: It's an local artifcatory , which don't have saspy but jaydebeapi
I am in Testing,
my developers did work using Java, jdbc drivers
so I am looking into using jaydebeapi
there must be a way?

Comment: Do you have all the sas jars that sas depends on? You have to specify all of them.